# Why can't I get my Azure, WCF, REST, SSL project working? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: wcf, rest, ssl, azure

I'm trying to get SSL, WCF and REST under Azure, but the page won't even load.

Here are the steps I followed:

1) I mapped the www.mydomain.com CNAME to my azuresite.cloudapp.net

2) I procured an SSL certificate for www.mydomain.com and properly installed it at my azuresite.cloudapp.net hosted service project

3) I deployed my WCF REST service to Azure and started it. Below is my web.config configuration.

The http (non-https) binding version worked correctly. My service URL, http: //www.mydomain .com/service.svc/sessions worked just fine.

When I deployed the project with the web.config below, enabling SSL, https: //www.mydomain .com/service.svc/sessions does not even pull up at all.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="Service">
               <!-- non-https worked just fine -->
               <!--
                 <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService" behaviorConfiguration="RestFriendly">
                </endpoint>
                -->
            <!-- This does not work, what am I doing wrong? -->
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="IService" behaviorConfiguration="RestFriendly">
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RestFriendly">
                <webHttp></webHttp>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="TransportSecurity">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you add the https endpoint to your web role in the ServiceDefinition.csdef file?

It should look something like this:

```
<WebRole name="WebRole">
  <InputEndpoints>
    <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80" />
    <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443" />
  </InputEndpoints>
</WebRole>
```

See http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2009/05/12/https-endpoint-on-windows-azure.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing a service behaviour. Try adding this:

```
   <serviceBehaviors> 
    <behavior name="RestService"> 
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" /> 
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" /> 
    </behavior> 
   </serviceBehaviors>
```

Then when you define your service:

```
   <service behaviorConfiguration="RestService" name="WebService.Rest">
```

**Edit**

Another thing that could be the problem, is that the request is not reaching your webrole. Have you set up an inputEndpoint for SSL? see [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davethompson/add-ssl-security-to-your-azure-webrole)