# Allow WCF to work over REST HTTPS on Azure

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, rest, azure

I have a WCF based REST web service up and working over HTTP.

If I try to access it over HTTPS I get a 404 error. I need HTTPS to work properly, because the service will primarily handle state changes made by users in the browser over AJAX. And if I try to call the web service with `.ajax` I get an error.

`http://site/svc/core.svc/dowork  == working`

`https://site/svc/core.svc/dowork  == 404`

Here is the basic code:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string DoWork();

    public string DoWork()
    {
        return "hullo";
    }

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureBinding">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <services>
      <service name="Fusion.core" behaviorConfiguration="Fusion.CoreBehavior" >
        <endpoint contract="Fusion.Icore" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" address="" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Fusion.CoreBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Try to see on how to host WCF on Azure with https that might be helpful (ex: http://holsson.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/securing-a-wcf-service-in-windows-azure-with-ssl/). Also have a look at this question on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204615/why-cant-i-get-my-azure-wcf-rest-ssl-project-working-what-am-i-doing-wrong)